# Origin of Charge Neutrality

Tags: condensed-matter

What is the origin of the "charge neutrality" requirement in solids?  Why do we require the bulk to be charge neutral, yet the surface can have a net charge?

Comment: Assume some modest level of non-neutrality (say one electron charge per 100 atoms) and figure the forces on a macroscopic sample of that stuff. Now try is again at $1\ e/\text{million atoms}$. Can you put a limit on the reasonable level of non-neutrality for, say glass or any other material of your choice?

Answer (score -1):

In a conductor the charge is free to be repelled to the surface, where its as further as it can be from each point. In a sphere it would even do that uniformly
[image: Charge conducting sphere].

In an insulator the charge is not free to move, but the electrons will start spending "a little bit" more time wherever they cancel the charge out. Which in the end causes the charge to manifest as a dipole on the surface.

Comment: Would the down-voter please explain in the comment why this should be downvoted? If I am misinformed I would like to know why.